# SAS Studio - Changing the Data Type of an Imported Excel File

Tags: sas

I am trying to upload an excel dataset to SAS Studio and change the data types and formats. Is there a task that can perform this or code? I am new to coding so it would be great if you could provide some help with the coding.

Thank you!

Comment: How did you import the Excel file? If you are reading from an XLSX file then SAS should match the formatting of the source file. But of course since Excel is a spreadsheet the columns might not have consistent data types for all cells. You could fix that on the Excel side.  What have you tried on the SAS side to create new variables with the desired type from the ones you got from converting the Excel file?

Comment: I tried running code like the following new = input(work.import.World_Rank, 8.);

Comment: That syntax doesn't look correct. Variable names cannot have periods in them unless you set VALIDVARNAME=ANY and even then you would need to code them using a name literal.Try a statement like this   `new=input(left(World_Rank),32.);` inside of a data step.